# Proving the bijection in quotient map

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, quotient-spaces

I'm currently stuck on a math problem, here is the instruction :

"Let R be the equivalence relation on N × N defined as follows:
(m1, n1) ∼ (m2, n2)
if m1 + n2 = n1 + m2.

Let f : N × N → N × N/R denote the quotient map, and consider the
function g : N × N → Z defined as g(a, b) = a − b. Show that g can
be identified with the quotient by R: that is, show that there exists a
bijection h: N × N/R → Z"

I have proven the existence of h using the **universal property of the quotient** (because h ◦ f = g). But I can't quite prove that it is a **bijection**. I have tried to prove the injectivity of h by proving the injectivity of g, but somehow I can't prove its injectivity (maybe g isn't injective ?). And for the surjectivity I have no idea. Or maybe I should prove the bijection using cardinals ?

I'm a 1st year maths student btw, thank you in advance :)

Comment: Hints: Under what conditions does $g$ map two pairs to the same integer? Does $g$ map onto all integers?

Comment: @blargoner g maps two pairs (let's say $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$) to the same integer if $a-b=c-d$ which means if $a+d=c+b$. This means that $g$ pairs two pairs to the same integer if these two pairs are in R. I used this exact property to prove $h$ existence. And yes $g$ maps to all integers I think...

Comment: So is $g$ injective then? Are those the only conditions under which $g$ maps two pairs to the same integer? If so what does that tell you about $h$? If $g$ is surjective what does that tell you about $h$?

Comment: @blargoner Yes, I forgot. If $a=b$ and $c=d$ then g maps these two pairs to the same integer $0$. But that doesn't tell me anything about g being injective right ? Because g maps from $N \times N$ to $Z$ so if $g(a,b) = g(c,d)$ --> $(a,b)R(c,d)$ or ($ a=b$ and $c=d$), this doesn't imply that $(a,b)=(c,d)$ which would be true if g was injective. So i would say that g isn't injective. And when I think about it, g being injective wouldn't even imply that h is injective. On the contrary, g being surjective would mean h to be surjective as well right ?

Comment: Right, $g$ is definitely not injective. There are infinitely many pairs of naturals with any given integer difference. But $g$ is surjective so $h$ must be surjective. So you're halfway there.

Comment: @blargoner any tips for the injectivity ? feels like I did the easy half...

Comment: Suppose $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on a set $X$, and let $f \colon X \to X/{\sim}$ be the quotient map. If $Y$ is any other set, and $g \colon X \to Y$ a function with the property that $\forall x_1,x_2 \in X : x_1 \sim x_2 \implies g(x_1)=g(x_2)$, then there is a function $h \colon X/{\sim} \to Y$ such that $h \circ f = g$. Moreover, if $g$ also satisfy that $\forall x_1,x_2 \in X : g(x_1)=g(x_2) \implies x_1 \sim x_2$, which is the same as $\forall x_1,x_2 \in X : h(f(x_1))=h(f(x_2)) \implies f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then $h$ is injective.

Comment: @azif00 I understand why $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$ is the same as $h(f(x_1))=h(f(x_2))$, but why is $x_1 \sim x_2$ the same as $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ But thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: @Wicowan That’s just because, given $x \in X$, $f(x)$ is its equivalence class $[x]_\sim := \{y \in X : x \sim y\}$. It is well-known that for two $x_1,x_2 \in X$, $[x_1]_\sim = [x_2]_\sim$ if and only if $x_1 \sim x_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing what's been covered in the comments:

First for $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{N}$ since $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ means $a+d=b+c$, which implies
$$g(a,b)=a-b=c-d=g(c,d)$$
it follows from the universal property of the quotient map $f:\mathbb{N}^2\to\mathbb{N}^2/{\sim}$ that there is a unique map $h:\mathbb{N}^2/{\sim}\to\mathbb{Z}$ with $g=h\circ f$.

To prove that $h$ is surjectve it is sufficient to prove that $g$ is surjective, because if $y=g(a,b)$ then $y=h(f(a,b))$. But $g$ is surjective, since for any $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ we can find $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ with $a-b=z$ and hence $g(a,b)=z$. For example if $z\ge0$ we can take $a=z$ and $b=0$, and if $z<0$ we can take $a=0$ and $b=-z$. In fact there are infinitely many possible choices of $a$ and $b$.

To prove that $h$ is injective, suppose that $h(f(a,b))=h(f(c,d))$. Then
$$a-b=g(a,b)=g(c,d)=c-d$$
so $a+d=b+c$, which means $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$, which implies $f(a,b)=f(c,d)$ by definition of the quotient map $f$. The injectivity of $h$ now follows since $f$ is surjective.